# Tomcat 7 not getting started from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have Strucked with a annoying problem, I had installed `eclipse EE` for working under JSP & Servlets, I had installed `WTS` from Install New Software , I have installed tomcat7 from `apt-get install tomcat7`, now I want to integrate tomcat7 with eclipse,

I have created a dynamic web project and when I try to Run the project as Run on Server, a window "Run on Server" comes up and asking me to select a server -

1. Exsiting (which is already disabled)
2. Manually --> in manually tomcat veriosn 3 to 8 are there, when I click on tomcat7 then server host name comes as localhost and servername is blank and does not allow me for next/finish button, when I click on tomcat8, server host name as localhost and servername as Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is coming,now this time next/finish button is enable, I click on next button, it ask me Specify the installation directory - I browse it and select the tomcat7 from `/usr/share/applications/tomcat7` ,it is saying  The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 7.0.52 (Ubuntu).  A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected. now "next/finish" button is disabled, I am very upset how it will be rectified, my project submission last date is tomorrow.I have work till night.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If tomcat7 from `apt` installed correctly try to select another `Tomcat installation directory` in your first screenshot, in `Manually -->` section. Select Apache Tomcat v7.0 and installation directory should be `/usr/share/applications/tomcat7` not `/usr/share/tomcat7`

[image]

If it is not work do this:

Download tomcat7 from [official site](http://supergsego.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.55/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.55.tar.gz)

Extract downloaded file somewhere, by default it downloads to `~/Downloads`:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ tar -xvf apache-tomcat-7.0.55.tar.gz
```

Now in `Manually -->` section in your first screenshot choose Tomcat installation directory as /home/$USER/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.55

Comment: @cOrpThough this helped me a bit, i downloaded Sysdeo and set preference to path of downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.55, now it is working fine, for that problem, if i give path /home/$USER/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.55, still giving the same problem as ......A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected. , Anyway Thanks for your time..

Comment: Did you change $USER to your username? And do not choose Tomcat8.0, choose Tomcat 7.0 on previous screen

Comment: where to change $USER to username, i have not changed it ??,  second if i select tomcat 7.0 on previous screen then next/finish button is disabled.

Comment: @Aman substitute $USER with your user name in `/home/$USER/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.55`. Open terminal and type `echo $USER` of don't know username. If you select tomcat 7.0 on previous screen, on the next screen in `Tomcat intallation folder` enter this path `/home/$USER/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.55`

Comment: @cOrp - As i have told, if i select tomcat 7 then next/finish button is automatically disable (please see - http://postimg.org/image/4z3u0bw29/) and if i select tomcat 8 and go to next and put /home/$USER/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.55, still does not work (please see - http://postimg.org/image/t52oabo5l/ )